# How can i test "private" methods of an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

Supose that i have this:

```
var myObj = (function() {
    function private1() {
        console.log("private");
    }

    return {
        public1: function() {
            private1();
            console.log("public");
        }
    }
})();
```

How could i test the "private1" function?

Comment: I know that this is a tricky question, because i am suposed to code thinking in how am i going to test my code.

Comment: The function can't be called from outside the closure, so you can't unless you add a testing API explicitly.

Comment: I'd argue that unit tests typically test the public API.

Comment: @Pointy _technically_ it can unless something like SES is used but generally you are correct. OP - you cannot test 'private1', simple `return` it if you need a reference to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out [How to test private functions in javascript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/). Summarizing the post, you could achieve what you want by improving your build process. If you use grunt to build your code then you could add some pieces of code that exposes the private elements of your IIFE only at testing time.

Also you may want to try this build tool [selectizer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/selectizer). With it you could define your private1 function as a module and then testing it by just loading the function with requireJS.

Comment: While very correct, could you please include the main points of that article in your answer instead of [only posting a link to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)?